# Plotting an x-axis for an FFT of a recorded signal

Tags: python, matplotlib, fft

I am missing something very obvious here, because I'm fairly new to this. I have read some tutorials and asked around but I still struggle to wrap my head around it. I have a 3 second audio recording, which I attempt to filter and then perform FFT to see if I was successful. However the x-axis I plot is obviously wrong (it's simply an np.arange() of the same size as the array that fft returns).

So far I have the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import fft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sounddevice as sd

fs = 44100
s = 3
recording = sd.rec(int(s*fs), samplerate = fs, channels = 1)
fft_r = fft(recording)
plt.plot(np.arange(22050), abs(fft_r[:22050]))
plt.show()
```

among other things but they are irrelevant to this problem...

[image]

the plot is nice and all but I sincerely doubt i produce frequencies this high :D

How would I correctly plot the x-axis for an fft of a recorded audio signal that lasts 3 seconds and was sampled at 44100 Hz? Any elaboration on the calculation I'd appreciate because I would very much like to finally understand...

Comment: You need to create a frequency variable... https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fft.html

Comment: @JodyKlymak what is 800.00 in the context of that example? is it something we arbitrarily choose or?

Comment: It is the sample rate in Hz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on np.fft.fftfreq() and np.fft.fftshift() try adding this in to your code. fftfreq will return sample frequencies and fftshift will centre the zero frequency component, try what I have below or try taking out the shift and seeing the difference.

```
fs = 44100
s = 3
recording = sd.rec(int(s*fs), samplerate = fs, channels = 1)
x=np.fft.fftfreq(len(recording),1/fs)
x=np.fft.fftshift(x)
fft_r = fft(recording)
plt.plot(x, abs(fft_r[:22050]))
plt.show()
```